# Making image-border width go inward instead of outward?

Tags: html, css

Simple problem really. I have some buttons which use border-image. the image they use have large rounded corners, so the inner box where the content goes is always padded by loads of border.
I want to make it so the button adapts the text's width, but have the text go right to the edges.
Basically the large gap between text edge and border edge needs to be eliminated.

Here's an example of what I've got and what I want to alter:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekazkw79/)

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 30px;
  border-image: url(http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/images/qml-borderimage-tiled.png) 30 30 fill round;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  TEXT TEXT TEXT
</div>
```

So even though it would look awful in that example, I want to the text edges to be touching the border-image edges.
I've tried 'box-sizing:border-box;' but this appears to only work for normal borders.

Comment: use Box-shadow without blur...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the `TEXT TEXT TEXT` in a `<span>` in the **HTML** then you can position it:

```
<div class="a">
    <span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
</div>
```

If you then add the following **CSS**, the text will run from the left border of the button to the right border:

```
.a span {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
```

The `left:` position and the `margin-right:` are both derived from the button's existing `border-width:`.

Basically:

- `left:-10px;` moves the left-hand edge of the `<span>` leftwards by one third of the `30px` width of the left border.
- `margin-right:-20px;` moves the right-hand edge of the `<span>` rightwards by one third of the `30px` width of the right border, as well as compensating for the `10px` leftwards shift declared in the rule above.

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 30px;
  border-image: url(http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/images/qml-borderimage-tiled.png) 30 30 fill round;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.a span {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but I found using 'margin: 0 -10;' does all that in 1 line.
Thanks!